# Sitecore restrict users from accessing the page using Sitecore security

Tags: security, login

[image: I have restricted the the access for the role "**AdminUser**" in the Access viewer as below.]

I have restricted the the access for the role "**AdminUser**" in the Access viewer as above.
Later in the code when I am accessing using the below code

```
 try
            {
                if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(@"Sitecore\AdminUser"))
                {
                    isAuthenticated = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(@"Sitecore\AdminUser", true);
                }
            }
```

It is authenticating the user and I am able to see the user role in the Sitecore.Context.User.Roles as "**Admin User**"

But when we access the Page it loads well and fine. Is there a way I can stop the user with Role "AdminUser" from accessing the page

**Note:** I am not accessing the item from Sitecore but as a webpage.

http://domain/Support/Global-editor

Comment: Does "Admin User" also have the "Administrator" box checked for the user? If so, all security is ignored.

Comment: No, It is not an administrator role

Comment: My guess is that Sitecore still thinks "Extranet\Anonymous" is the user. Try outputting the current user in your view somewhere to see what user Sitecore is using.

Comment: @Meghan were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are restricting the wrong domain. In your code you are checking against the Sitecore domain but you said you are accessing the page as a webpage which by default uses the Extranet domain.
More information on domains can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/security_domains).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sestocker, May be Sitecore still thinks extranet\anonymous is the user. Debug your code and check what is the context user after your login code. If it does not work I have a auto login code in my blog which also uses Sitecore Ticket manager please try that. This was provided by Sitecore Support.

https://singh-prabhat.blogspot.in/2016/12/sitecore-enable-preview-mode-for.html

Comment: As it stands this is a link only answer. Please see our guidelines on [What makes a good post](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post) and [What is a link only answer](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/why-was-my-answer-converted-to-a-comment-what-is-a-link-only-answer?s=1|0.8389)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this, Create a new role, let's say "AccessExternalPageName" by default add this rule to all other users and remove this role to Sitecore\AdminUser

Now in you above code check the user role in.

We have tried a type of the same scenario where security access was not captured then added some custom role and identified those checks.